# Use PowerShell to Scrape WebPage That Uses Single Sign On?

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, webrequest

My goal is to scrape a web page using PowerShell, which I can do usually. However, I'm trying to open a specific URL in IE. The page that comes up uses single sign on in the IE browser. Is there a way to do this with invoke-webrequest (without a user entering credentials?) Or another way to get the data off of the page?

It's assumed the user running the script has access to the site/URL.

Comment: How does the user magically have access to the site/URL without first entering a username/password?  If it's being grabbed from the current windows session, you can use the `-UseDefaultCredentials` switch on `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: The force is strong with this one. That did the trick thank you.

Comment: Great, I've posted it as an answer for future searchers.  Feel free to upvote/mark as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize the `-UseDefaultCredentials` switch on `Invoke-WebRequest` to grab the current user's session.